# ¿Como ver las entradas mas recientes de mi blog en pagina principal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

lo que sucede es que tengo un sitio web en el cual tengo integrado un blog en wordpress, y lo que quiero hacer es que las entradas mas recientes se muestren en la pagina de inicio de mi sitio, pero no se como hacer esto, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu página principal no es Wordpress, para integrar los últimos posts de tu blog debes conocer la ubicación del archivo `wp-blog-header.php` que existe entre los archivos de tu Wordpress. Luego, tienes que incluir esto en la página de inicio de tu sitio:

```
<?php
// Incluye el archivo "wp-blog-header.php"
require_once('/path/a/wp-blog-header.php');
// Obtiene las 10 últimas entradas del blog, ordenadas por título
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
// Recorre las entradas para mostrarlas en una lista
foreach ($posts as $post): 
    setup_postdata($post);
    the_date(); // muestra la fecha
    the_title(); // muestra el título
    the_excerpt(); // muestra el resumen 
endforeach;
```

Lo anterior está tomado del Códex de Wordpress, donde hay otros ejemplos: [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website#Examples).